# What is the StorageQuotaAllocated means in SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, storage-quota

I have a little confusion about this Storage Quota Allocated property in SharePoint Online.

If i ran `Get-SPOTenant`, I get the  `StorageQuota : 1304576` & `StorageQuotaAllocated : 104962048`.

**StorageQuota** property make sense as it is my total storage of the Tenant which is 1.24TB But what is this `StorageQuotaAllocated(100TB)` numbers are ?

**Note:** I check the Quota Allocated to all my Sites in the Tenant which 325TB (13 sites each with 25tb limit).

If i run the `Get-SPOGeoStorageQuota` then the results are same which are on our Tenant Admin page.

```
GeoLocation : NAM
GeoUsedStorageMB : 99
GeoAvailableStorageMB : 1304477
GeoAllocatedStorageMB : 0
TenantStorageMB : 1304576
QuotaType : Allocated
```

What is the `StorageQuotaAllocated` means? from where these numbers are coming?

Answer (score 0):

The StorageQuotaAllocated gets the value of the storage quota that is allocated for all sites in the tenant.

And per my test in my SharePoint online environment, then I get the value of StorageQuotaAllocated. And it is the sitecollectionnumber*25TB.

More references:

[Tenant.StorageQuotaAllocated property.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.online.sharepoint.tenantadministration.tenant.storagequotaallocated.aspx)

[Manage site collection storage limits.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-site-collection-storage-limits)

Comment: thank you for the answer, but Myster is still there, how it is calculated? as i mentioned i have 13 site collections and in that case it should be show as 325TB but it is showing 100 TB....how it calculate, which site collections it consider etc?